# how to show text data(read from text file) as page wise in java?

Tags: java, text-files, filereader

I have text file ,which contains example 200 lines of data.I'm able to read text file data using java in my program.But the issues is i want show the text file data in page wise format.How can i do it? Till now i did this.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        String currentLineData;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\testdocument.txt"));
        while ((currentLineData = br.readLine()) != null) {
          //out.println(currentLineData);
        }
```

Please guide me.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: number of lines in a page is the property of the editor and not the file. So, it might be different for different editors. You can actually "set" number of lines (say 20) and consider it to be one page.

Comment: @TheLostMind,Could you please help me code wise.

Comment: The actual question is *how do you define* a page?.

Comment: @TheLostMind,consider 20 line per page i have to show and i will make previous and next buttons to show remaining pages.

Comment: Do you want to display the lines as and how you read them or read them all once and then display them ?

Comment: @TheLostMind,read them all once and then display.

Comment: where are you storing the "lines read from the file"?. In a StringBuilder?

Comment: @TheLostMind,Storing all data in (br)buffer reader variable.

Comment: You need to store the data in a StringBuilder or something.